# How to hide a div with nested div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to Javascript (and JQuery) and Web Development itself, so I'm having problems trying to show the whole content of the div `service_info` (that is hidden) when I select one the option in my `<select>` with id `service_type`.

Here is the code, using materialize.css and MDL both declared in the `head` tag. jQuery 2.2.1 is declared in the `head` tag before MDL's and materialize's scripts.

```js
$('#service_type').change(function() {
  $('#service_info').show('slide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="service_type" name="service_type">
      <option disabled selected value="">
          Scegli un tipo di servizio
      </option>
      <option value="discharge">
          Dimissioni
      </option>
      <option value="transfer">
          Trasfermimento struttura
      </option>
      <option value="examination">
          Visita di controllo
      </option>
      <option value="admission">
          Ricovero in casa di cura o clinica
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col s12" id="service_info" hidden>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <input class="mdl-textfield__input" id="place_from" name="place_from" type="text">
      <label for="place_from">Indirizzo del luogo di partenza</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <input class="validate" id="place_to" name="place_to" type="text">
      <label for="place_to">Indirizzo del luogo di arrivo</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <input class="validate" id="section" name="section" type="text">
      <label for="section">Reparto</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot understand why nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Where is the code you have declared? Before or after the HTML? Or is it inside a `document.ready` statement?

Comment: it is inside <scipt> tags inside <head> tags and inside $(function() { });

Comment: It's working perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/j072nm3m/ Can you try to place console.log('test') to your javascript so you can see it's being executed?

Comment: Show with slide is a jQuery UI feature. I hope the jQueryUI.js reference included. Also, do you see any console errors? May be you have jQuery conflicts.

Comment: @MartinGottweis WOW! I tried with JSFiddle trying to include every CSS and JS from Materialize and MDL but it didn't manage to load...

Comment: It must be something with those inclusions...

Comment: I can't seem to recreate the issue. Can you work with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0md38a80/

Comment: @TheNobleSix upload more code, we will find the issue, don't worry. Maybe save the jsfiddle(update button at the top) and we can make that work.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! It works now with `display:none`! It was an error with a previous declared function... can't believe it...

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#service_type').change(function () {
                $('#service_info').show('slide');
            }); 
        });    
</script>
```